# Monthly Mythology Reading Group -- Would you be interested?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, myth-of-the-month

I was wondering if there is interest in a monthly mythology reading group; it would be conducted similarly to the [Buddhism Stack Exchange's monthly reading group](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/the-book-of-the-month-is-good-question-good-answer). Basically, we would select a myth to read every month, read it, and then ask questions about the myth on the site.

While we all seem to read a lot, I think we should aim to read shorter myths, or maybe specific sections of larger myths/books. That way everyone can fit the reading into their schedule.

Judging by the upvotes, there is clearly interest in this, so please nominate books/myths that you would be interested in reading by adding an answer to this question, and I (or anyone else) will create a [myth-of-the-month](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myth-of-the-month) meta post for whichever text has the most upvotes.

---

1. [Myth of the Month #1: Gylfaginning](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/myth-of-the-month-1-gylfaginning)
2. [Myth of the Month #2: The Epic of Gilgamesh](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/myth-of-the-month-2-the-epic-of-gilgamesh)
3. [Myth of the Month #3: Lebor Gabála Érenn](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/myth-of-the-month-3-lebor-gab%C3%A1la-%C3%89renn)

Comment: I think it's a good idea: a bit similar to the concept of [the weekly topic challenges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) that some beta do, but with a focus on the myth sources themselves.

Comment: @plannapus we could do weekly topic challenges, but I think monthly would allow people to do more research, and the topics that we would choose would probably be myths themselves.

Comment: I don't think we need another meta post, anyone interested in participating  should go ahead and nominate books/myths with an answer here.

Comment: @Yannis done [additional text to go over length minimum]

Comment: This would have to be something that anyone could do a quick google search to find. Arthurian Legends are good as well as some of the classical Greek Myths. I would suggest maybe something between 10-20 pages long so it doesn't seem like a task to read. But I would definitely give this my stamp of approval.

Comment: Like I need another reason to add to my growing reading list. Yeah, I'll probably try. lol

Comment: How would this work?  I can't read Sumerian or Ancient Egyptian or Ancient Greek or Latin or vulgar Latin (of Dante) or Old English or Finnish or Chinese etc in original, and it's *very* hard to get good translations of most works, so you'd have to plan a lot of time ahead.  I mean, I know some of you can read Latin and Ancient Greek or Old English at least, so don't let me stop you have your fun, but still, do you have some plan for others?

Comment: That's unless you're planning to read one of the very few works where it's easy to find translations, such as the Bible, the Iliad and the Odyssey, and perhaps Sophocles, but those are exactly the myths people here would have already read anyway.

Comment: @b_jonas we're reading texts that have english translations. We didn't plan anything for people who don't feel comfortable reading in english, but our current myth -- The Epic of Gilgamesh -- is well known and should have good translations in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

The [popol-vuh](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popol-vuh). It's reasonably short, has excellent translations available online, and is reasonably complex. It's also relatively short, and you can skip some parts of it at the end if you don't want to read the whole thing.

Comment: Here is a [literal translation](http://www.mesoweb.com/publications/Christenson/PV-Literal.pdf) and a [less literal one](http://www.mesoweb.com/publications/Christenson/PopolVuh.pdf).

Comment: @plannapus - Goodness, I appreciate having some explanatory notes as much as the next guy, but those footnotes are out of control.

Answer (score 3):

I might as well nominate something [arthurian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthurian), so I'll suggest [the Three Arthurian Romances](http://www.ancienttexts.org/library/celtic/ctexts/index_welsh.html).

They're each fairly short, and each one comprises a new story, but they're still all linked.

They comprise one of the more "modern" mythologies - to some extent - and they feature an interesting setting, and some really unpronounceable names.

Plus, I think a lot of us have thought about being in the Arthurian world . . . once upon a time.

Answer (score 3):

The Táin Bó Cúailnge (The Cattle Raid of Cooley)

It's a well-known and famous [irish](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish) story, and it's only one story so it would be short.

translation: http://www.yorku.ca/inpar/tain_faraday.pdf
tag: [tain-bo-cuailnge](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tain-bo-cuailnge)

Comment: You know I'm down for the Tain.  My thoughts on sources:  Online, I prefer this one: http://adminstaff.vassar.edu/sttaylor/Cooley/ (side-by-side is kinda nice, I find it a bit more readable, and Faraday lacks some things I expect, like the first two chapters at this link).  If you're willing to get a print version, I say go for Kinsella: http://www.amazon.com/The-Tain-Translated-Irish-Cuailnge/dp/0192803735 (which isn't available online anywhere I have found)