# Myth of the Month #1: Gylfaginning

Tags: discussion, status-completed, myth-of-the-month

Let's get started! Since plannapus's nomination had the most upvotes, I decided to go with reading [Gylfaginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gylfaginning), the first book of the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda). The book deals with various subjects including the creation and destruction of the world, and it's ca. 20k words.

Translations exist online:

- Wikisource: [English](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Prose_Edda/Gylfaginning), [German](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Edda_(Simrock_1876)/Snorra-Edda/Gylfaginn%C3%AEng), [French](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99Edda_de_Snorre_Sturleson/Le_Voyage_de_Gylfe)
- Sacred Texts: [English](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre04.htm)
- [Old Norse](http://www.heimskringla.no/wiki/Gylfaginning)

In order for the myth of the month to be successful, it is important that ***everyone*** commit to doing the following:

1. **Read the story!**

   It is not that long, it's really interesting (particularly if you are interested in [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse) mythology), and most importantly, *in order for everyone to discuss the story we all have to read it*.
2. **Participate in the discussion!**

   Please join us in the [Myth of the Month chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24847/myth-of-the-month) to discuss the text.
3. **Ask a question on the main site!**

   As always, if you have any questions about the myth don't forget to [ask them](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)! Make sure they are tagged [gylfaginning](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gylfaginning) so they can be found and answered by people with knowledge of the text.

This can be really fun: Gylfaginning sounds like a really interesting text, and I'm looking forward to reading what everyone has to say about it. Remember, the more people who participate, the more fun this will be.

If you are a really fast reader and Gylfaginning is too short for you, or if you just aren't interested in the Gylfaginning, there are [two other books in the Prose Edda](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Prose_Edda/Gylfaginning) that you could try.

If this is successful and people want to do it again, I (or someone else) will choose another text from our [list of suggestions](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/monthly-mythology-reading-group-would-you-be-interested) (either randomly or by upvotes). Please continue to nominate interesting (and reasonably short) texts so we will still have stuff to read.

And let's all thank plannapus for the fantastic recommendation!

Comment: What's the deadline, teach?

Comment: @fredsbend let's say sometime in July. Take your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the [questions our first myth of the month generated](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgylfaginning%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2015-06-13..2015-07-14):

- [Who fathered Gefjun's ox sons?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/922/who-fathered-gefjuns-ox-sons)
- [According to the Gylfaginning, where do giants live?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/925/according-to-the-gylfaginning-where-do-giants-live)
- [Does Odin choose who enters Valhalla?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/929/does-odin-choose-who-enters-valhalla)
- [Why is Vidar silent?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/937/why-is-vidar-silent)
- [Why does Óðr (Oder) travel away from Freyja?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/945/why-does-%C3%93%C3%B0r-oder-travel-away-from-freyja)
- [Who is the sword juggler in the Gylfaginning?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/951/who-is-the-sword-juggler-in-the-gylfaginning)
- [Why is Gylfe trying to deceit his way into Asgard?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/957/why-is-gylfe-trying-to-deceit-his-way-into-asgard)
- [Significance of Gylfi's choice of pseudonym](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/981/significance-of-gylfis-choice-of-pseudonym)
- [Does the Prose Edda have a Hungarian translation?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/does-the-prose-edda-have-a-hungarian-translation)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite possibly the best idea for this site. Allowing people to immerse themselves further into the myths and to be able to ask questions is fantastic.

I tip my hat to all involved and wish you success.