# Myth of the Month #2: The Epic of Gilgamesh

Tags: discussion, status-completed, myth-of-the-month

I've picked fredsbend's suggestion, the [Epic of Gilgamesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh), as our second [myth of month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/57).

Here's an English translation of the myth:

- [THE EPIC OF GILGAMESH,The Babylonian Epic Poem and Other Texts
  in Akkadian and Sumerian, Translated and with an introduction by ANDREW GEORGE](http://www.cidmod.org/sidurisadvice/Gilgamesh.pdf) [pdf]

As with the [Gylfaginning month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/57), I'd like to invite everyone to:

1. **Read the story!**
2. **Participate in the discussion!**

   Join us in the [Myth of the Month chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24847/myth-of-the-month) to discuss the text.
3. **[Ask a question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/ask) on the main site!**

   If you have any questions about the myth don't forget to ask them! Make sure they are tagged [gilgamesh](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gilgamesh) so they can be found and answered by people with knowledge of the text.

Comment: Does this last only *this month* (i.e. the rest of July) or *for one month* (i.e. till mid August)?

Comment: @ChristianRau Till mid August. That said, perhaps we could give it an extra couple of weeks and run it till the end of August, and have an actual per month cycle starting September.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the [questions our first myth of the month generated](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?q=[gilgamesh]+is%3Aquestion+created%3A2015-07-14..2015-09-21):

- [What does Gilgamesh's title "He Who Saw the Deep" mean?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/what-does-gilgameshs-title-he-who-saw-the-deep-mean?s=1|4.9258)
- [How does Shamhat know about Gilgamesh's dreams?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/how-does-shamhat-know-about-gilgameshs-dreams?s=2|4.2961)
- [What is the context behind Gilgamesh's rejection of Ishtar?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/context-behind-gilgameshs-rejection-of-ishtar?s=3|2.9675)