# Myth of the Month #3: Lebor Gabála Érenn

Tags: discussion, myth-of-the-month

I've picked femtoRgon's suggestion, the [Lebor Gabála Érenn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebor_Gab%C3%A1la_%C3%89renn), as our third [myth of month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/57).

Here's an English translation of the myth:

- [Lebor Gabala Erenn: The Book of the Takings of Ireland, better known as The Book of Invasions](http://www.maryjones.us/ctexts/leborgabala.html)

As with the [Gylfaginning month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/57) and [Epic of Gilgamesh month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/277/183), I'd like to invite everyone to:

1. **Read the story!**
2. **Participate in the discussion!**

   Join us in [our site's general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23261/the-pantheon) to discuss the text.
3. **[Ask a question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on the main site!**

   If you have any questions about the myth don't forget to ask them! Make sure they are tagged [lebor-gabala-erenn](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lebor-gabala-erenn) so they can be found and answered by people with knowledge of the text.