# Could this site do topic challenges?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

What are this site's thoughts on doing topic challenges? It would help encourage questions on the site and attract new users. I also think it would be interesting for already established users, encouraging people to explore myths or pantheons they haven't read about.

---

Since this seems to have decent consensus, I have started a new post to collect ideas for topic challenges: [Ideas for topic challenges](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/ideas-for-topic-challenges). Please contribute your thoughts!

Comment: Yes please! We tried [myth of the month](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myth-of-the-month), and it was fun for a while but I guess people lost interest. A topic challenge may be easier for people to get into, though. Do you have a specific topic in mind you'd wish to explore?

Comment: Related across the network: [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/162704), [topic-challenge questions on Meta Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topic-challenge), [challenge questions on Meta Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge).

Comment: https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/monthly-mythology-reading-group-would-you-be-interested has a nice list of potential myths

Answer (score 3):

### Yeah, we totally should!

Topic challenges are awesome. They'll attract more attention the site, encourage more questions and activity, and also just be plain interesting. We can also use them to encourage questions about seldom-asked-about topics. If there's sufficient agreement, I can start a thread to collect ideas for topic challenges.