# September Topic Challenge: Australian Aboriginal mythology

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

HDE 226868's answer was the highest voted answer on my [question requesting possible topic challenge ideas](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/409/57), so the subject of his answer will be the September topic challenge:

> ## Australian Aboriginal mythology
>
> Example myths/topics:
>
> - The "[Dreamtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamtime)" (as named by anthropologists)
> - The [Rainbow Serpent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Serpent)

---

**What is a topic challenge?**

During a topic challenge, community members read and ask questions about a particular topic.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other topics are always welcome as well, but they won't count as a part of this challenge.

**How does one participate?**

To participate in this topic challenge, all one has to do is ask or answer a question related to *Australian Aboriginal mythology* from today until the end of September 2017. That simple! Questions asked in the scope of this topic challenge should be tagged with [indigenous-australian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indigenous-australian).

**What else?**

- Vote [here](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/ideas-for-topic-challenges) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Answer (score 5):

List of [questions for September Topic Challenge](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bindigenous-australian%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2017-08-24..2017-09-30):

- [Why is the Loch Ness monster all the way from Scotland draw so many parallels with the Hawkesbury river monster?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/why-is-the-loch-ness-monster-all-the-way-from-scotland-draw-so-many-parallels-wi)
- [What legends inspired Cleverman's Hairypeople?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/what-legends-inspired-clevermans-hairypeople)
- [How does Australian Aboriginal totemism compare to its Native American parallels?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/how-does-australian-aboriginal-totemism-compare-to-its-native-american-parallels)
- [Is there a relationship between the Dreamtime and dreaming?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-dreamtime-and-dreaming)
- [Why does the Yara-ma-yha-who live on fig trees?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2920/why-does-the-yara-ma-yha-who-live-on-fig-trees)
- [What is Thardid Jimbo's story?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/what-is-thardid-jimbos-story)
- [What do we know of the Willauk, the Tebwem and the Pioial?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/what-do-we-know-of-the-willauk-the-tebwem-and-the-pioial)