# October Topic Challenge: Navajo mythology

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This month, we will go with [Heather's suggestion](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/410/57):

### The Navajo mythology

A topic not much covered on the site, which also is readily readable about.

Example myths/topics:

- [Diné Bahaneʼ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Din%C3%A9_Bahane%CA%BC) - Navajo creation myth
- The origin of the [Blessingway](http://www.hanksville.org/voyage/navajo/BlessingWay.php3) ceremony (link is to explanation of ceremony)
- Characteristics of [Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote_(Navajo_mythology))

---

**What is a topic challenge?**

During a topic challenge, community members read and ask questions about a particular topic.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other topics are always welcome as well, but they won't count as a part of this challenge.

**How does one participate?**

To participate in this topic challenge, all one has to do is ask or answer a question related to *Navajo mythology* anytime during October 2017. That simple! Questions asked in the scope of this topic challenge should be tagged with [navajo](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navajo).

**What else?**

- Vote [here](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/ideas-for-topic-challenges) for the next topic challenge, or propose your own!

Comment: [Navajo Legends, Myths, and Stories](http://www.native-languages.org/navajo-legends.htm)

Answer (score 2):

List of [questions for October's topic challenge](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bnavajo%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A2017-10):

- [What is the significance of the kinds of wood used in sweat lodges?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/3025/what-is-the-significance-of-the-kinds-of-wood-used-in-sweat-lodges)
- [How does one become a skin-walker?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/3026/4105)